# How to assign the multiple values of an output to new multiple columns of a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, apply

I have the following function:

```
def sum(x):
    oneS = x.iloc[0:len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    twoS = x.iloc[len(x)//10:2*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    threeS = x.iloc[2*len(x)//10:3*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    fourS = x.iloc[3*len(x)//10:4*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    fiveS = x.iloc[4*len(x)//10:5*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    sixS = x.iloc[5*len(x)//10:6*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    sevenS = x.iloc[6*len(x)//10:7*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    eightS = x.iloc[7*len(x)//10:8*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    nineS = x.iloc[8*len(x)//10:9*len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    tenS = x.iloc[9*len(x)//10:len(x)//10].agg('sum')
    return [oneS,twoS,threeS,fourS,fiveS,sixS,sevenS,eightS,nineS,tenS]
```

How to assign the outputs of this function to columns of dataframe (which already exists)

The dataframe I am applying the function is as below

```
Cycle   Type    Time
1   1   101
1   1   102
1   1   103
1   1   104
1   1   105
1   1   106
9   1   101
9   1   102
9   1   103
9   1   104
9   1   105
9   1   106
```

The dataframe I want to add the columns is something like below & the new columns Ones, TwoS..... Should be added like shown & filled with the results of the function.

```
Cycle   Type    OneS    TwoS    ThreeS
1   1           
9   1           
8   1           
10  1           
3   1           
5   2           
6   2           
7   2
```

If I write a function for just one value and apply it like the following, it is possible:

```
grouped_data['fm']= data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type'])['Time'].apply( lambda x: fm(x))
```

But I want to do it all at once so that it is neat and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
def f(x):
    out = []
    for i in range(10):
        out.append(x.iloc[i*len(x)//10:(i+1)*len(x)//10].agg('sum'))
    return pd.Series(out)


df1 = (data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type'])['Time']
                         .apply(f)
                         .unstack()
                         .add_prefix('new_')
                         .reset_index())

print (df1)
   Cycle  Type  new_0  new_1  new_2  new_3  new_4  new_5  new_6  new_7  new_8  \
0      1     1      0    101    102    205    207    209    315    211    211   
1      9     1      0    101    102    205    207    209    315    211    211   

   new_9  
0    106  
1    106
```

Comment: @AndyHayden - ooops, you are right, answer was changed.

Comment: the new columns should be added to a seprate dataframe (which already exists and has few column that have 'grouped' values) and not to the original dataframe. In my question, i have show the df i am applying the function on & the df in which i want to add the results. You first solution worked but it created a new df called "groupeddata" & hence the existing values in that dataframe all got disturbed & was looking wierd

Comment: @mohanys - Not sure if understand, please check edited answer.

Comment: i need only one row for each grouped item, that is 1 row for 1,1 & 9,1. The results should be like what you have done in the first answer (adding the results to data_train_bel1800). so, there should be 10 columns added with the output of function assigned to each column. So, with the data I have posted, the grouped_data df would be shape 2,12

Comment: This works. however, in my case df1 already existed, so the new values are not adding to that, but if df1 did not exist, it is working ok. so, i made this as file line of my code (that way df1 is created) but i am unable to add columns to it. For example my code `df1['mean'] = data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended'].mean()` throws an error "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

Comment: what i meant was what i wanted to added these values to an existing dataframe? anyway, i have made it work. Also, I removed `.reset_index()` in you code. with that, i can additional column without transform. One strange thig is happening though, i get valeus for new_0 & new_1 columns only, the rest are zeroes!

Comment: now, what if i want to add to 'mean' values to the same dataframe(df1 in your answer) using a similar function?

Comment: @mohanys - Just tested and I was wrong with transform. Need `df1 = df1.join(data_train_bel1800.groupby(['Cycle','Type'])['Detrended'].mean().rename('mean'), on=['Cycle','Type'])`

Comment: Last question on this. What if i want to add to 'mean' values to the same dataframe(df1 in your answer) using a similar function?

Comment: @mohanys - ca you be more specific?

Comment: in you code we had function 'f' that divided the group into 10 parts calculated the `sum()` of each part. Then we created df1 which has these results. now, i have function 's' that is exactly as 'f' but calculates `mean()`. i want the result of function 's' to be added to df1 (10 additional columns). The shape of the resulting data frame should be 2,22

Comment: the formula in the function needs an small change it should be `out.append(x.iloc[i*len(x)//10:(i+1)*len(x)//10].agg('sum'))` we should have `(i+1)`, if not it will not work properly because multiplication & division will happen first & then addition.